# Change of a coordinate and the resulting field equations in GR

Tags: general-relativity

I am a bit troubled by this result, and don't know why. Let me explain:

I have this line element:
$$
ds^2=-e^{2F(r)}dt^2+e^{2H(r)}dr^2+r^2d\theta^2+r^2\sin^2(\theta)d\phi^2 \tag{1}
$$

When I calculate the Einstein tensor, for example the $\theta\theta$ component, I obtain:
$$
G_{\theta\theta}=r e^{-2 H} \left(r F''+\left(r F'+1\right) \left(F'-H'\right)\right) \tag{2}
$$

Now, I want to make a change of the coordinate $\theta$, of the form:
$$
\mu=cos(\theta) \tag{3}
$$

I have two ways of reaching the final field equations, with this change of coordinate:

1. To change the coordinate in the line element, before calculating the new field equations, or;
2. To make the change of variable in the old field equations directly;

The problem is, I don't get the same results.

Let's get to the conversions. First, the conversion of the line element $(1)$. After doing $\mu=cos(\theta)$, I obtained:
$$
ds^2=-e^{2F(r)}dt^2+e^{2H(r)}dr^2+\frac{r^2}{1-\mu^2}d\mu^2+r^2(1-\mu^2)d\phi^2 \tag{4}
$$

And the $G_{\theta\theta}$ component is:
$$
G_{\theta\theta}=\frac{r e^{-2 H} \left(r F''+\left(r F'+1\right) \left(F'-H'\right)\right)}{1-\mu
   ^2} \tag{5}
$$

Now, if I directly convert $(2)$, with $\mu=cos(\theta)$, nothing changes, since this expression for $G_{\theta\theta}$ has no references to $\theta$:
$$
G_{\theta\theta}=r e^{-2 H} \left(r F''+\left(r F'+1\right) \left(F'-H'\right)\right) \tag{6}
$$

And so, I have the question:

What am I doing/thinking wrong? Shouldn't $(5)$ and $(6)$ be the same?

In $(5)$ I did the coordinate change prior to the calculation of the Einstein tensor. In $(6)$ I did the change afterwards. Thanks in advance, feeling dumb here.

Comment: They should not be the same, no, since the tensors are *covariant* and not invariant.

Comment: What actually is preserved with the use of tensors is the form of equations that are written using tensors. However the components of the tensors themselves might change. Hence, the relation that you use to get to the Einstein Tensor from the metric tensor would remain same irrespective of the use of the coordinate system, but the components of the tensor might change. For example, the tensor equation $ds^2=g_{\mu\nu}dx^{\mu}dx^{\nu}$ remained the same when your metric was any of as in equation 1 or 4. But the components of the metric tensor itself change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you get equation $(6)$ it looks like you've simply not considered the tensor transformation law. $G_{\mu\nu}$ transforms as: $$G_{\mu'\nu'}=\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x^{\mu'}}\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial x^{\nu'}}G_{\mu\nu}$$

You are making the change of coordinates $r'=r,t'=t,\theta'=\cos\theta,\phi'=\phi$. This is a pretty simple change of coordinates. We find then: $$G_{\theta'\theta'}=\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial \theta'}\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial\theta'}G_{\mu\nu}=\left(\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial\theta'}\right)^2G_{\theta\theta}=\left(\frac{1}{1-\theta'^2}\right)G_{\theta\theta}$$
Which is exactly your equation $(5)$. In getting to the final answer I used the fact that all of the terms in the summation are $0$ except for the $\partial\theta/\partial\theta'$ term and the fact that $\partial\theta/\partial\theta'=-1/\sqrt{1-\theta'}$.

For clarity I've changed your notation of $\mu$ to $\theta'$ in this answer. I wanted to avoid having confusion with the $\mu$ dummy indices in the tensor transformation law. Your error is producing equation $(6)$ without consideration of the actual tensor transformation law.